# Verify Firebase ID Token with Firebase-PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-authentication, token

I am using Firebase-Auth to authorize an user on my web-app coded in PHP. The Authorization itself is made with Javascript, which is executet on an Ajax-Request to verify, that an user is logged in.

To use the Firebase-Admin at the server I have implemented [Firebase-PHP](http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io).

On every AJX-Request I now get the logged in user ID and the ID Token, which I want to verify in PHP like it's been written [here](http://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/authentication.html#verify-a-firebase-id-token) in the Docs.

The verification itself works fine. If the token exists I get an "IDToken"-Object. But how can I get the userID out of that object again to verify, that the token is the right one to that user?

```
$idTokenString = '...';

try {
    $verifiedIdToken = $firebase->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($idTokenString);
    // This is the Token-Object where I cant't find the uid-get-Function
} catch (InvalidIdToken $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I couldn't find a method in the documentation or in the classes I searched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maintainer of the library here - the documentation was indeed missing that information, but it is now included and the whole page has been overhauled:

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#verify-a-firebase-id-token

You can retrieve the UID from the `sub` claim of the ID token:

```php
try {
    $verifiedIdToken = $firebase->getAuth()->verifyIdToken($idToken);
} catch (InvalidToken $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    
$uid = $verifiedIdToken->getClaim('sub'); // lcobucci/jwt:^3.0
// or 
$uid = $verifiedIdToken->claims()->get('sub'); // lcobucci/jwt:^4.0

$user = $firebase->getAuth()->getUser($uid);
```

Comment: My $verifiedIdToken is verified successfully but when getClaim('sub') is called I'm getting Call to undefined method Lcobucci\JWT\Token\Plain::getClaim() I'm using "lcobucci/jwt": "^4.0" in composer json may I know what should be problem, googled a lot but no solution found

Comment: @ShriramPanchal I updated the answer with the usage for `lcobucci/jwt:^4.0`, and the outdated documentation as well, thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thanks for the update saved a lot, if possible, one update in SDK initialization like $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount('google-service-account.json'); would save a lot search efforts for upcoming users

Comment: sweet answer :*

Comment: what is the $idToken in the param?