# Use firebase token authentication with laravel API

Tags: php, angular, laravel, firebase-authentication, jwt

I have a project in which i have the FE with Angular 2+ and the backend it's with Laravel. I call the APIs to retrieve the necessary data, i use JWT for authentication with Laravel. All works fine there.

So, i want to use the token provided by firebase and authenticate it in laravel as the same way it's done with the middleware that the jwt-auth package with laravel provide. The reason to use firebase it's that makes very easy to login with Google, Twitter, etc.

To verify the token i know that i need to decode the token and check several things in the payload. So my questions are:

1. It's only necessary to check the payload data, or something else
   also?
2. There is any package that make it easier to work with this token
       with laravel?

If someone knows a good article or video that talks about this, it would be very appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package made exactly for this by Firebase: [Firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

You can add it to your project by running `composer require firebase/php-jwt`

To decode the JWT you can run: `$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $key, array('HS256'));`

Generally, if you are the holder of the secret key and you can decode the JWT without a validation error then you should be able to rely upon it for identifying a user.  However, you probably want to add in additional security checks.

Comment: Downvoters, can you please explain your reasoning for the downvotes?

Comment: Or just use the php sdk which I think also makes use of this package.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761310/verify-firebase-id-token-with-firebase-php